# How do I append a large amount of text to a file using Ansible?

Tags: linux, ansible, devops

Our application creates a lot of definitions in `/etc/services`. We keep a `services` file handy with all these definitions so that we can just pipe them into `/etc/services` like this:

```
cp /etc/services /etc/services.stock
cat /path/to/build/services >> /etc/services
```

It works, but it's not idempotent i.e. running these commands repeatedly will cause the services file to get appended with the info again.

As I work through our Ansible playbooks, I'm trying to figure out how to do this. I could so something like this:

```
- command: "cat /path/to/build/services >> /etc/services"
```

but I don't want it to run every time I run the playbook.

Another option is to do something like this:

```
- name: add services
  lineinfile: 
    state: present
    insertafter: EOF
    dest: /etc/services
    line: "{{ item }}"
  with_items:
   - line 1
   - line 2
   - line 3
   - line 4
   - ...
```

but this is really slow, because it does each line individually.

Is there a better way? Templates don't help, because they'd totally overwrite the services file, which seems a little rude.

Comment: Not an ansible user, but can you do something like this: 1) if and only if file `/etc/services.stock` is not present then `cp /etc/services /etc/services.stock`.  2) `cat /etc/services.stock /path/to/build/services >/etc/services`.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

[`blockinfile`](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/collections/ansible/builtin/blockinfile_module.html) is a native, idempotent module to ensure a specified set of lines is present (absent) in a file.

Example:

```
- name: add services
  blockinfile: 
    state: present
    insertafter: EOF
    dest: /etc/services
    marker: "<!-- add services ANSIBLE MANAGED BLOCK -->"
    content: |
      line 1
      line 2
      line 3
```